# .htaccess | Adding A Second Vanity URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want to take my .htaccess file and add a second rule for another vanity URL as I already have one declaring the page. So how would I write it so I can go to my page, and the next vanity being a variable for a profile?

```
Ex:// mywebsite.com/page/profile
```

Here is my current .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make an example.

Your current url is `http://domain.com/myurl`, which point on `http://domain.com/index.php?p=myurl`
You'll be able to add a vanity url for this page with this kind of htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^myvanityurl/?$ myurl [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Then, `http://domain.com/myvanityurl` will redirect to `http://domain.com/myurl`

If you want this redirection to be transparent (aka, keep `myvanityurl` in the url bar), remove the tag `R=301` from the rule.

---

**EDIT**

After your edit, this is what you're searching for :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?p=$1&profile=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1&profile=$2 [L]
```

Then, `http://domain.com/edit/756` will redirect to `http://domain.com/index.php?p=edit&profile=756`

This code can be simplified by :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&profile=$2 [L]
```

Comment: So how would I write it so I can go to my page, and the next vanity being a variable for a profile?

EX:// http://mywebsite.com/page/profile